# Center a Shape layer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a small problem. I updated my phone to iOS 14 and my loading screen has moved for some reason to the top left of the screen.

Here is what it looked like before the update:
[image: Here is the before]

Here is the after

[image: Here is the after]

Here is after the update:

Here is the code:

```
 func loadingScreen(){
        // set the circle for loading screen
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        //pulsating layer
        pulsatingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pulsatingLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pulsatingLayer.lineWidth = 20
        pulsatingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        pulsatingLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        pulsatingLayer.position = view.center
        view.layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)
        
        //track Layer
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        trackLayer.position = view.center
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        //animate method
        animatePulsatingLayer()
        
        //red circle
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer.position = view.center
        shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        //add percetntage
        view.addSubview(percentageLabel)
        percentageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        percentageLabel.center = view.center
    }
```

Comment: Could you add `print("ViewCenter: \(view.center)"` when `loadingScreen` is called? It might be called before layout subviews, so the center is not correct yet. In didLayoutSubViews, update the centers of the different layers.

Comment: will try now @Larme

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You do not want to use `view.center`. That is where the view is in the coordinate space of its superview. Sure, if the view’s `frame` happens to be the same as its `superview.bounds`, referencing `view.center` will coincidentally return the same `CGPoint`, but it suggest a fundamental misunderstanding of the two different coordinate spaces.

   You want to use `CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)`. The `bounds` is the coordinate space of the view to which you are adding this shapelayer. Referencing `center` (or `frame`) are incorrect, because they are not coordinates within this view, but rather those within the view’s superview.
2. The center of a view may change. First, if you access this too early in the view lifecycle, it may be `.zero`, only later getting updated to the correct value (which is what your screen snapshot suggests is going on here).

   But rather than just deferring this (e.g. to `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`), the better solution is to move the building of the path for the shape layer to the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the view controller, or, better, the `layoutSubviews` of the `UIView`. That way, not only are you guaranteed that it will happen at the right point during the app lifecycle, but you’ll also correctly update your UI when there is an orientation change, introduction of split view multitasking if on iPad, constraints are reapplied for any reason, etc.

Comment: Thank you, This helped me a lot! I call the function from the "viewDidLayoutSubviews" function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your CAShapeLayer position under adding sublayer:

```
pulsatingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pulsatingLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
pulsatingLayer.lineWidth = 20
pulsatingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
pulsatingLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
view.layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)
pulsatingLayer.position = view.center
    
//track Layer
trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
trackLayer.position = view.center
    
//animate method
animatePulsatingLayer()
    
//red circle
shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
shapeLayer.position = view.center
```